# Angular unit tests: mat-table problem with conflicting components inside of table header's cell

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, jestjs, mat-table

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my custom table component. The problem is that even with `should create` test it's throwing me the error that I can't fix. I tried many different variants but none of them did't help.

[image]

The column has to be sortable so I have to use `mat-sort-header` and probably also `*matHeaderCellDef` because it's throwing another error related to `template of undefined` without it. Does anybody knows how I should change it?

Comment: It seems like you have the definition of `*matHeaderCellDef` directive in two places. One is probably coming from the module and another probably is coming from a mock.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix that issue? I don't get it - I need to have columns as sortable so there has to be `mat-sort-header`, when I remove it then no error appears but it has to be there. Also when I remove `*matHeaderCellDef` then table will not render..

Comment: I would remove the directive in declarations and keep the module, see if that works.